# Ionic Serve throws a Type-Error: Appscripts.serve

Tags: ionic-framework, ionic2, ionic3, typeerror, sourceforge-appscript

I recently cloned a project and when I tried to serve it, I got an error:`TypeError: AppScripts.serve is not a function`.

How would I go about fixing this issue/where should I look?

I have already tried updating ionic, and reinstalling all plugins(just in case).

Assistance on this would be greatly appreciated !

Comment: it might be a problem with your package.json file. Can you check it ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is the same as mine when trying serve old project in updating Ionic3, all gonna error something like that, but when start a new project again its gonna work well

Answer (score 26):

Execute this command:

`npm install --save-dev @ionic/app-scripts@latest`

After that your app should work using

```
ionic serve
```

Comment: This would be the correct answer. Helped me. Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Running this command works for me

```
npm install --save-dev @ionic/app-scripts@latest
```

and then

```
ionic serve
```

Answer (score 0):

I face the same issue when i started developing old ionic 2 project with ionic 3.
follow the following steps works for me :

```
npm cache clear

delete the node-modules folder

npm install

npm install --save-dev @ionic/app-scripts@latest

ionic serve
```